# javascript/html - change color of checkbox text when box if checked by user

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to change the color of my checkbox text label when the user checks the box and clicks the toggle button. I looked up other examples and tried to make my own solution below but it doesn't work when I check the boxes I want to check and click the button. I was wondering why?

```js
function addItem() {
  var input = document.getElementById("textbox");
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("checklist_items");
  if (input.value.trim() != "") {
    var new_element = document.createElement("DIV");
    new_element.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"> ' + input.value;
    wrapper.appendChild(new_element);
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = '';
  } else {
    alert("You must enter at least 1 character.");
  }
}

function toggleItem() {
  var chkbx = document.querySelectorAll('checklist_items');
  if (chkbx.checked) {
    document.getElementById('checklist_items').style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("checklist_items").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

  }

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Checklist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div><h1>My to-do list</h1></div><br />
     <div id ="myCheckList">Enter an item:</div>
     <div>Type something: <input type="text" id="textbox"></input></div>
     <input type="button" id="addBut" value = "Add item" onclick="addItem()"/>
     <input type="button" id="toggleBut" value = "Toggle highlight" onclick="toggleItem()"/>
 
     <script src="addHandler.js"></script>
     <div id="checklist_items"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How my program works is the user enters a bunch of text in the textbox and clicks the add button, which creates a checkbox for their input. I want the name of their input beside the checkbox to change colors when I check it and click the toggle button.

Comment: Hi Dobrikella, looks like you are not using properly `querySelectorAll` and `document.getElementById("box")`, box id element does not exist

Comment: Inputs are self-closing and can't contain any descendants, so no `</input>`

Comment: You aren't showing this in your example, but does your `checklist_items` DIV contain a bunch of checkboxes and you want to change the background color of the checkbox labels if the boxes are checked? If so, please update your example to show us what the checkboxes and labels look like

Answer (score 1):

`var chkbx = document.querySelectorAll('checklist_items')` needs to be `var chkbx = document.querySelectorAll('#checklist_items')` or `var chkbx = document.getElementById('checklist_items')`.
`querySelectorAll` takes CSS selectors as arguments, which are either html elements or class or id names with the corresponding prefix. IDs have the prefix `#` and classes have the prefix `.`

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$(".your_checkbox_class").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).css("background-color","your_color_here");
    }
};
```

EDIT:
You should also give this checkbox class or id

EDIT 2:

document.getElementById('checklist_items').style.color = "red";

means that **font color** will change but checkbox has no text

Comment: is it running perfectly? I am trying to create a checkbox from the system that once it is checked, the button on the front page is changed to its color. is it possible to use this code? what should be the code for the checkbox?